# Does SChannel support key update requests for TLS v1.3?

Tags: winapi, openssl, tls1.3, schannel

How can I request a key update on a TLS v1.3 connection implemented with Win32's SChannel?

In other words, what is the Win32 function that provides similar functionality as [`SSL_key_update()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_key_update.html) in OpenSSL?

I did not find any useful information in the Win32 documentation. It seems to suggest that `InitializeSecurityContext()` (client side) or `AcceptSecurityContext()` (server side) may provide this functionality, but when I call this with the current security context as suggested in [Renegotiating an Schannel Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/renegotiating-an-schannel-connection), I get `SEC_E_OK` but no data is returned that I could send to the other side.
And I see no flag/parameter where I could specify the update type, as in `SSL_key_update`.

Comment: Didn't `InitializeSecurityContext` (client side) or `AcceptSecurityContext` (server side) return *phNewContext*?

Comment: No. I pass the same pointer to phContext and phNewContext and it is unchanged.

Comment: Is it still unchanged with [a new credential *phCredential* and optional *fContextReq*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/renegotiating-an-schannel-connection)?

Comment: I provide the same phCredential as for the initial handshake. The output buffer is set to NULL/0. The question is: Is this the correct way to request a TLS v1.3 key update and if yes, which parameters are necessary in this situation, and where is this documented?

Answer (score 0):

NO. If providing the same *phCredential* as for the initial handshake, What do you want to update?
As [Renegotiating an Schannel Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/renegotiating-an-schannel-connection) you attached said,

1. Update credentials if applicable and/or context attributes.
2. [EncryptMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/encryptmessage--schannel) the generated `PSecBufferDesc pOutput`.
3. Send the Encrypted data to the other side.
4. the other side [DecryptMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/acceptsecuritycontext--schannel) which return `SEC_I_RENEGOTIATE` the data.
5. the other side [return to the negotiation loop and call AcceptSecurityContext (Schannel) or InitializeSecurityContext (Schannel), pass SECBUFFER_EXTRA returned from DecryptMessage()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/decryptmessage--schannel#return-value)

Comment: What I want is to update the key  and initialization vector of the sending stream and request the same from the other side for the other direction, as described here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-4.6.3 . Does this really require new credentials?

Comment: NO. You just need to update the **necessary** context attributes.

Comment: Which context attributes must be updated to request the key update?

Comment: Consider [`(A/I)SC_REQ_USE_SESSION_KEY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/context-requirements)?

Comment: No, it does not trigger a key update. I get SEC_E_OK and no data that I should send to the server side.